# Applescript - need to run command in applescript

Tags: applescript

I need to run the following command in apple script 
"rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/Apple\ -\ Safari\ -\ Safari\ Extensions\ Gallery; \"
I am receiving an error when i attempt to compile with this command:
do script "rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/Apple\ -\ Safari\ -\ Safari\ Extensions\ Gallery; \"in window 2

is pointing to the space before the dashes, i know the command is accurate because i manually run it in terminal regularly.

Comment: The problem is with how you're escaping the spaces. Is that the exact command that you use in terminal? I do not think it's correct... you even have an escape \ for the last character.

Comment: @jweaks It is kinda hard to tell because he didn't `back tick` his code to show what's code or not. In Terminal, if you don't want to quote a file path, yet it has spaces, then you would escape them as above. He also may have code after he isn't showing judging by the semi-colon.

Comment: there are other lines of code before and after this line

Comment: the first line is:
mv ~/Library/Safari ~/Desktop/Safari-`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`; \

Comment: the command I enter into terminal is exact except for the quotation marks

Comment: the following lines clear other caches and plists but the commands are similar

Comment: I am receiving an error at the dashes, the other command is giving me an error is:

rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/Apple\ -\ Safari\ -\ Safari\ Extensions\ Gallery; \

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured out your problem. In Terminal this would work okay because you are escaping spaces in the file path by using `\` so it reads okay. When you enter a `\` in Applescript then it works the same and escapes the next character, but it actually doesn't show up in Terminal when you run it.

There are two methods to handle this.

A. Escape the `\` in Applescript so it shows up in Terminal by putting another one. Here's an example:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/Apple\\ -\\ Safari\\ -\\ Safari\\ Extensions\\ Gallery;
```

B. Quote your file paths and remove the `\` altogether. Here's an example:

```
rm -rf '~/Library/Caches/Apple - Safari - Safari Extensions Gallery';
```